# using core-js with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript1.5

The Kangax compatibility table for ES6 at http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ shows results for "TypeScript + core-js".  I need core-js in order to use ES6 methods like String#startsWith.  I haven't been able to figure out how to tell the TypeScript compiler to consider core-js and couldn't find an example.  How can I use core-js with TypeScript?

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to use the standard ES6 definitions from typescript? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/bin/lib.es6.d.ts Or do you mean how would you load the library?

Comment: Ah, yes I can use that! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you using Typescript 2.0, you can use `@types` to solve this issue.

`@types` and types

When you compile typescript code, by default all visible `@types` packages are included in your compilation. Packages in `node_modules/@types` of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within:

- `./node_modules/@types/`,
- `../node_modules/@types/`,
- `../../node_modules/@types/`,

and so on.

[`@types/core-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/core-js) provide the definition for core.js, you can install it as another modules.

`npm install --save-dev @types/core-js`

More information at: [tscconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The Typescript repo provides [standard definitions for ES6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts) functionality.

I suppose if you wanted to use some of core-js's functionality that is beyond ES6, you would have to add definition files yourself.